# How can I get maximum complex value from an array of complex values(524289) in python?

Tags: fft, python

I have an array of complex values. Actually this array contains fast Fourier transformation fft values. now I want to fetch maximum complex value from the array. Thanks

Comment: Maximum absolute value, maximum real value, or maximum complex value?

Comment: I want to fetch maximum complex value from the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Maximum" is ambiguous when it comes to complex values.  The complex value itself doesn't have a min or max.  Which is greater, `1+0j` or `0+1j`?  What about `1+0j` and `0+.5j`?  The answer to these questions determines what exactly what you want to do.

You can get the maximum real part (`max(1+0j, 0+10j) == 1`), maximum imaginary part (`max(10+0j, 0+1j) == 1`), maximum absolute value (`max(10+0j, 0+1j) == 10`, `max(1+0j, 0+10j) == 10`), complex value with the maximum real part (`max(1+0j, 0+10j) == 1+0j`), complex value with the maximum imaginary part (`max(10+0j, 0+1j) == 0+1j`), or complex value with the maximum absolute value (`max(10+0j, 0+1j) == 10+0j`, `max(1+0j, 0+10j) == 0+10j`).  All are possible with numpy arrays.

The default in numpy (`arr.max()` or `np.max(arr)` when `arr` is complex) is the complex value with the maximum real part.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random(1000)+np.random.random(1000)*1j  # generate example data

maxreal = arr.real.max()  # maximum real part
maximag = arr.imag.max()  # maximum imaginary part
maxabs = np.abs(arr).max()  # maximum absolute value

maxcompreal = arr[arr.real.argmax()]  # complex value with maximum real part
maxcomp = arr.max()  # complex value with maximum real part, same as above
maxcompimag = arr[arr.imag.argmax()]  # complex value with maximum imaginary part
maxcompabs = arr[np.abs(arr).argmax()]  # complex value with maximum absolute value
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex numbers don't have an ordering. But you can calculate the squared magnitude $\text{re}(x)^2 + \text{im}(x)^2$ where $re(x)$ is the real part of the complex number $x$ and $im(x)$ is its imaginary part (with the imaginary unit removed). Scan your array and find the largest squared magnitude. You might be able to use the built in function `max`, possibly with a custom ordering function.